# Disable hang dump generated by dotnet test

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, dotnet-test

When I run `dotnet test ... --blame-hang-timeout 2000` it generates a 'Hang Dump' which grows into gigabytes. This feature is available since .NET 5.0, and the [Microsoft pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) refer to a `DUMP_TYPE`. Because of this size, I want to disable the generation of this dump but keeping the `--blame-hang-timeout`. However, I don't see any information on this `DUMP_TYPE`. Is it possible to disable or limit the dump information?

Comment: I read _The type of crash dump to be collected. It should be full, mini, or none. When **none** is specified, test host is terminated on timeout, but no dump is collected. Implies --blame-hang._ Are you looking at a translated version? `none` is probably the dump type you want

Comment: O wow, must have overlooked it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I tried it out, but when having '--blame-hang-dump-type none' it still generates those folders.

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15555